# Does Payflow Pro Recurring Billing support IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, payflowpro

Does Payflow Pro Recurring Billing support IPN? I tried with DPRP(Direct Payment Recurring Payment) & it's sending me IPN message just fine.

But after lots of research as well, couldn't able to figure out a way to incorporate IPN for Payflow Pro Recurring Billing.

There is one feasible way, that I can see at this point of time, is the ”Inquiry” action to get the profile/payment specific detail. But for that, I have to run a cron, which’ll check the status/payment detail of the profile every time it runs, which I think will be cumbersome.

People, Can anyone please shade any insight into it?

Comment: Hello Manash khamari,
I am also want to use IPN in Payflow recurring.
there any option exist for IPN in Payflow.

Answer (score 3):

PayPal confirms that there is no IPN service available for PayFlow pro Recurring Payment.
As you already know the INQUIRY action is one option. The other option is to fetch the reports from PayPal manager periodically.

Comment: Hi Raj,Thanks for the update. Actually I need to update my tables as per the payment happen for each recurring payment, I guess INQUIRY is the option, I have to live with.

Comment: Is this still true to this day? We have use the inquiry option in 2016?

Comment: Hello @DevinWalker, I am also want to use IPN in payflow recurring. There any option exist in payflow in 2018.

Comment: Nope, you can to do some crazy trickery to match up IPN calls to Payflow records... typical PayPal.